# Eclipse font is at the wrong place?

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts

[image: Font at wrong place]
The font in eclipse Text Editor is at the wrong place when i scroll the scrollbar.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? Which *editor* inside Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when scrolling horizontally in the editor, using the scroll bar.

Moving the cursor, or clicking in the editor makes the affected lines be rendered correctly. Scrolling up and down renders all lines correctly.

Comment: yes it works. I use mbp2018 and can this problem solved permanently? When i use windows it didn't happen.